# Is there a datepicker for bootstrap 3 that works well with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I've seen a few questions about datepickers for bootstrap 3, a few questions about bootstrap3 + angularjs and a few about datepickers for angularjs. I also tried to search online but couldn't find a solution for a combination of all three.. Is there a good and simple bootstrap3 datepicker that works well with angularjs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The angular-ui datepicker works fine for me. I would suggest you to use that. `Datepicker (ui.bootstrap.datepicker)`. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ata3YOsl7p9hVNMRQFGT?p=preview) is the example plunker.

Answer (score 2):

the angular-ui team datepicker for bootstrap is pretty good.

Look here:
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

They recently upgraded to bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1):

Yes, angular-ui bootstrap has.

demo: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap